# Terminology regarding generic methods

Tags: c#, generics, terminology

I'm looking for a term descibing the Type that would replace  in an explicit implementation of a generic method.

My scenario goes something like this:

I'm happily pair programming with a dude by the name of Kent.
Kent writes a explicit implementation of the generic method in question and I want to tell him he's doing it wrong.

```
public void Foo<______> (______ buzz) 
{
    buzz.Bar();
}
```

So I say: " Hey Kent, you should change that ***_*** to MyClass"

Could someone please help me replace this **__** with something a bit smarter sounding? Maybe a "TargetType", "ExplicitType", or "thingamagig"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term is ["generic type parameter"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk36dx2.aspx).

> In a generic type or method definition, a type parameters is a placeholder for a specific type that a client specifies when they instantiate a variable of the generic type.

Answer (score 2):

It is a "generic type parameter".
From the [MSDN introduction to C# generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> **What Are Generics**
>
> Generics allow you to define type-safe classes without compromising
>   type safety, performance, or productivity. You implement the server
>   only once as a generic server, while at the same time you can declare
>   and use it with any type. To do that, use the < and > brackets,
>   enclosing a generic type parameter.

Answer (score 1):

It calls [Generic Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk36dx2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

A **`Generic type parameters`** is a placeholder for a specific type that a client specifies when they instantiate a variable of the generic type.

> Generics in .NET let you reuse code and the effort you put into implementing it.

```
public void Foo<T> (T buzz) 
{
    buzz.Bar();
}
```

In the above example a generic `Foo` `of Type "T"`, where the `T` is provided by the caller.